# Get Language Tag with Html-Agility-Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get the ISO Language Code from the html tag with html-agility-pack.
My code looks like

```
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
  UserAgent = "[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0]"
};
var doc = web.Load(url);
string lang = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html").InnerText;
```

But this gets of course the full html content.
So how to enter these tag?

```
<html lang="en">
```

edit:
DocumnetNode has no Attributres
[image]

Comment: Wouldnt that be the _DocumentNode_?

Comment: tried it with DocumentNode.FirstChild.... but this is <!doctype html>

Comment: The language (`lang="en"`) wouldnt be a child of DocumentNode, it would be an _attribute_.  So you should do `doc.DocumentNode.Attributes["lang"].Value`

Comment: see my edit...DocumentNode has no Attributes

Comment: i got it... doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[1].Attributes[0].Value; but this is not valid if a site has other elements between doctype and html tag..so if anyoune have a better way, please share

Comment: @Tobias can't you just use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html").Attributes[0].Value`?

Comment: @Justin yes, that works...strange...

Comment: @Tobias I'll post it as an answer then if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the language with the following code. It will get the `html` node and get the value of the `lang` attribute on that.

```
string language = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html").Attributes["lang"].Value;
```